# Как изменить цвет вертикальнoй полосы в vim

Tags: linux, vim

`:hi ColorColumn ctermbg=black` меняет цвет вертикальной полосы на черный.
Как мне записать в `.vimrc`, чтоб не писать это постоянно при открытии редактора?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set colorcolumn=120 " расстояние от левого края
hi ColorColumn ctermbg=black
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не меняется цвет.

Comment: @MikeRu странно, вот мой пример: [`~/.vimrc`](https://i.imgur.com/gdbSh4F.png), полоса на месте.

Comment: @MikeRu, возможно, значение переопределяется загружаемыми позже командами/плагинами/макросами. вы добавляли строки в конец файла `~/.vimrc`?

Answer (score 0):

Переместил строки в конец файла и теперь вертикальная полоса изменила цвет на желаемый, чёрный.

```
set colorcolumn=85
hi ColorColumn ctermbg=black
```