# Вертикальная линия в vim

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

Как в `vim` задать вертикальную линию через 80 символов от начала символов ?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542513/178576

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как изменить цвет вертикальнoй полосы в vim](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542504/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bdo%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-vim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропишите в Вашем `.vimrc` следующую строку:

```
set colorcolumn=80
```

Установить цвет линии можно, прописав перед вышеупомянутой командой следующую строку (поиграйтесь с цветом и найдите нужный Вам):

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=gray
```

P.S. На всякий случай - если у Вас нет файла `.vimrc`, просто создайте его в удобном для Вас редакторе в коневой директории Вашего пользователя (например, так: `nano ~/.vimrc` или `vim ~/.vimrc`)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте *:h 'colorcolumn'*

Более того, можно задавать эту колонку для конкретного файла: *:h modeline*